# Does some monitor technologies cause more eyestrain?

Tags: monitors

I have 30" 4K IPS LED, and have huge eyestrain.
Can IPS LED technology cause more eyestrain then others, what are reasons to eyestrain and tips to avoid it?

Comment: Well I don't know if this affects you or not certain shades of blue can cause eye strain.  The last time I went to my doctor they offered a coating to block these shades of blue.  Unfortunately,  I don't suffer from eye strain so I can't confirm or deny there effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Modern screen types themselves won’t change much in terms of eye strain, but some things that might make a difference are:

- **Screen size:** the bigger the screen, the further away you can sit from it comfortably, which can help with eye strain (I definitely noticed the difference when switching to a smaller screen)
- **Refresh rate:** Higher refresh rates make the screen appear smoother, which can help reduce eye strain. 60hz is what cheaper monitors tend to be but 120hz is a lot better (although a lot more expensive)
- **Brightness:** If a screen is too bright or too dark, it can contribute to eyestrain. Most monitors and OS have adjustable brightness, but of course different monitors will have different maximums and minimums.

Comment: "I definitely noticed the difference when switching to a smaller screen" You have more strain on smaller screen?  Refresh rate dont make a differnece at static pictures only at videos?

Comment: @user628075 I noticed it because I had it closer to my face and my posture was also worse (it was a laptop, the way I wrote it might be a little confusing) . It doesn’t just improve videos, anything that isn’t an instant change will be smoother such as scrolling too, which can help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to refresh rate, contrast and brightness, there are these to consider.

- Longer hours can cause more eyestrain, regardless of technology.
- If you are getting older, you may need to lubricate your eyes with eye drops
- Prolong blue light on the screens causes eye strain and difficulty in sleeping.

  - Windows has `Night Light Settings` that you can use reduce blue light on a schedule.
  - I use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) which gives you greater control over the spectrum and times.
  - Some monitors (such as HP) allow to use choose between Cool, Warm, Neutral and custom modes.